# How do I select a chunk of text and paste it to the current cursor position w/o using mouse in vim?

Tags: vim, copy, paste

I want to give up using mouse for selecting and pasting chunks of text within a buffer. Whats the most efficient way to do this with just kb? I mean navigate to arbitrary line, copy the substring, return to the previous position and paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go quickly to a line use the search by typing
`/SUBSTRING` and then Enter after you have found the correct substring.
Make sure to use hlsearch and incsearch
`:set incsearch` and `:set hlsearch`

When you are at the correct line, yank the whole line with `yy` or the whole word with `yaw`.
Then go back to where you started the search by typing two backticks ``` `` ```
Then you can paste your yanked line/string with `p`

Answer (score 5):

Very simple method:

1. Select the lines with `Shift-V`
2. "Yank" (=copy) the text with `y`
3. Paste the text with `p` at the position you want to.

There are of course many other ways to copy and paste, `yy` copies the current line for example.

Do the some VIM tutorials, it is better than learning everything bit by bit.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the tutorials, they helped me considerably when I started with vim. eg. http://www.vi-improved.org/tutorial.php

Answer (score 3):

- Mark your current position by typing `ma` (you can use any other letter instead of a, this is just a "named position register".
- navigate to the line and substring for example by using a `/` search
- yank text with `y<movement>` or mark it with `shift/ctrl-v` and then `y`
- move back to your previously marked position with ```a`` (backtick)
- paste your buffer with `p` or `P`

Comment: Nice explanation. This neatly pulls out any substring when you use the <movement> parameter effectively.

For example yf; moves from the current char forward to the first semicolon, which is end of line character for some programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

My normal method would be:

1. Use visual mode to select the text with <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
2. Yank using <kbd>y</kbd>
3. Go to the line you want to be on using `123G` or `:123`
4. Navigate where I want to be within that line with <kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>f</kbd>
5. Put the text with <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>P</kbd>

If you need to jump back and forth between the spots, I'd cycle through jumps using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use "p" to paste after the current line, and "P" to paste above the current line.

Comment: Ok. What about quickly navigating so some line (and substring withing the line) and back?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'the substring'.  If you want to copy line 50 to the current position, use:

```
:50t.
```

If you want to move line 50 to the current cursor position, use:

```
:50m.
```